# VueJs mounted nextTick function not being called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How do I get functionality to execute when switching between two components of the same type?

**The Problem:** I have several map and chart components that need to display different data.  When switching from a map to a chart component, the `mounted/nextTick` function runs as expected.  When switching from one map to another map, the `mounted/nextTick` function does not run which results in vue's model reflecting the change in current map but the DOM still showing the previous element.

**Another Example:** More generically, lets say I have components A and B.  The user creates A1, A2, and B1.  When the user switches between any component of type A and B ((A1||A2) && B1), the `mounted/nextTick` function runs as expected.  When the user shows component A1 and the switches to A2, the DOM continues to show the data for A1.

**Question:** How do I get the DOM to reflect changes from one component to another of the same type?

**Example:**

```
<side-bar></side-bar> <!-- List of elements to choose from (ex: map1, map2, graph1)-->
<template> <!-- The element to be shown with different data depending on which element was clicked -->
    <map v-if="active[0].type == 'map'" :data="changes"></map>
    <graph v-if="active[0].type == 'graph'" :data="changes"></graph>
</template>
```

Comment: Got some example code or even better, a JSFiddle demo?

Comment: Possible to add some code...

Comment: Components are reused, so lifecycle hook won't be called, watch for changes in `$route` instead

Comment: Add key props to same type of components, see https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

Comment: key props, I knew I had read something like this before!  I'll check when I get back if that fixes the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Manan Vaghasiya gave the proper solution.  Vue.js has a key prop that can be added to tell the Vue virtual DOM algorithm to treat each element as a separate item.  In code, this looks like this:

```
<template v-for="item in items">
    <custom-element :key="something.unique" />
</template>
```

This will allow multiple instances of the same custom component to be swapped and not treated as the same object which allows the `mounted/nextTick()` function to run every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vue-router, then you can use afterEach function:

```
router.afterEach( ( to, from ) => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;

  }, 100 );
} );
```

Full example you find here: https://github.com/tstabla/Vue.js-starter

Comment: this is all happening on the same route, it's basically a dashboard where users can change which graphs/maps/tables are being shown

Comment: So you probably need attach a watch method. 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers